# How to store Recycleview items into variables

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-maps

I have an android app,  that displays SQLite data in a recycle view and card view,

I want to use this data as parameters  ( dynamicly based on item position ) for click activity to show maps based  on 2 items  ( loaded from database ) latitude and longitude ,
i am using a button like this inside onBindHolder :

```java
    

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.example.mymy.Model.Sites;
import com.example.mymy.R;

import java.util.List;

class SearchViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView sitecode;
    public TextView address,lonit,latit,note;
    public Button visitLocation;


    public SearchViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        sitecode = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.s_sitecode);
        address = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.s_address);
        lonit = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.s_londit);
        latit = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(s_latit);
        note = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.s_note);
        
        visitLocation = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.Launch_bt);

    }
}
public class SearchAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SearchViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private List<Sites> sitesList;
    
    public SearchAdapter ( Context context, List<Sites> sitesList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.sitesList = sitesList;
    }

    @Override
    public SearchViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_item,parent,false);

        return new SearchViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull SearchViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.sitecode.setText(sitesList.get(position).getSitecode());
        holder.address.setText(sitesList.get(position).getAddress());
        holder.lonit.setText(sitesList.get(position).getLonit());
        holder.latit.setText(sitesList.get(position).getLatit());
        holder.note.setText(sitesList.get(position).getNote());
        

    holder.visitLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

                intent.setData(Uri.parse("geo:32.319366,36.236719")); //36.236719  32.319366

                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return sitesList.size();
    }
```

Comment: you can add the data in your list while you pass the recycler view list items data and use it with its position

Comment: @Wisam Jaradat Can you please post your complete Adapter code ?

Comment: What exactly do you mean "store recyclerview items in variables"? you mean you want a handle on each recyclerview item?

Comment: I mean I want to use  the data  ( latitude and longitude ) loaded from database as a parameter passed to a click , and opens location related to specific site:
insted of  using fixed values  in
       intent.setData(Uri.parse("geo:32.319366,36.236719"))

i need to use  : something like that  :
 intent.setData(Uri.parse("geo:" + Latitude +',' + Longitude ));

Comment: Do not use the RV data as the source, instead have a single source of truth and pull data from it (both for the RV as well as your "other screens"). When the data in the RV is changed (e.g. the user tapped an item), update your "single source of truth" or merely pass the "id" of the tapped item so the next screen can "fetch" the item from the Single Source of Truth and display it accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try one of these two:

You can either get it from the TextView in the cardview like so:

```
String label = " (any label you want)"
String strUri = "http://maps.google.com/maps?q=loc:" + holder.latit.getText()+ "," + holder.lonit.getText() + label;
intent.setData(strUri);
```

or you can get it from your list using the position like so:

```
String label = " (any label you want)"
int pos = holder.getAdapterPosition();
String strUri = "http://maps.google.com/maps?q=loc:" + sitesList.get(pos).getLatit() + "," + sitesList.get(pos).getLonit() + label;
Uri locationUri = Uri.parse(strUri)
intent.setData(locationUri);
```

I'm not sure but I think `label` is optional in both approaches.

Comment: thanks,  but it didn't work,  map opens but blank ( and hanging ) ,  for  both solutions and  the holder underlined , i don't know why or what does it mean here

Comment: Just edited my answer. give it another try.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by doing something like this in click listener as mentioned below:

```
    int pos = holder.getAdapterPosition();
    Uri locationUri = Uri.parse("geo:" + sitesList.get(pos).getLatit() + "," + sitesList.get(pos).getLonit())
    intent.setData(locationUri);
    context.startActivity(intent);
```